# SQL index for deleted_at columns

Tags: mysql, sql, database, indexing, relational-database

Is it a best practice or beneficial to add an index on the deleted_at column in a SQL database? Lots of my queries use WHERE deleted_at IS NULL, will adding a deleted_at index speed up my queries or slow them down?

Comment: What's the `deleted_at` column?

Comment: I use a deleted_at column instead of actually deleting the row, I will just update deleted_at to the current time stamp when a user wants to delete a row from the DB.

Comment: Whether you should index it depends on how well it partitions your table. If most rows are not deleted, indexing it won't help very much. Also, if you have other columns that you index, and you test them along with `deleted_at`, then you'll need a composite index of the other columns with `deleted_at` to get the benefit.

Comment: Consider adding deleted_at into your other indexes as the last column.

Comment: @Barmar - I think your comment should be the answer :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Barmar answered this question best:

"Whether you should index it depends on how well it partitions your table. If most rows are not deleted, indexing it won't help very much. Also, if you have other columns that you index, and you test them along with deleted_at, then you'll need a composite index of the other columns with deleted_at to get the benefit."